# How to change tab behavior in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have what I feel should be a very basic issue but I cannot find the setting nor do I know what to do. When I enter data into a cell and hit tab (on the keyboard) to move over to the next cell, it acts like I hit Ctrl+Enter and remains on the cell I entered data in. The same thing happens when I press enter. Instead of moving down after entering data, it stays on the active cell like I was holding Control.

I have ensured my Ctrl keys are not sticking. I have even tried changing the directions under the Advanced tab in setting when hitting enter. The result is the same.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Just in a particular workbook? Or in any workbook? Any macros in the workbook? Or have you opened any other workbooks recently with macros?

Comment: It is happening in all workbooks, and I have a hidden "Personal" workbook to apply macros to workbooks that don't have them. These macros do basic things like hide columns etc and haven't impacted this issue previously.

Comment: Would any of those macros have an Application.OnKey event that repurposes the Tab key? On in any workbook you've opened recently? Does restarting Excel fix the issue? I've previously used the OnKey to change the Enter and Tab behavior, and then forgotton to revert back, leaving users in the same situation as you seem to be in.

Comment: Hello, I was not aware of the Application.OnKey event so no, my macros do not contain them. However, since excel has restarted today everything is working the way I expect it to. I'll be on the lookout for any other spreadsheets with macros that may do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my further years of experience, what I believe may have happened on this particular day is in testing of macros, I included some code that attempts to optimize things, such as `Application.DisplayUpdates = False`. When testing the macro, if the code failed, it never re-enabled those options.

When working with VBA, if Excel starts to behave in a way I described above, I recommend running a code that will turn all of Excel's default features back on. This has helped me several other times when Excel started behaving strangely.